# Spring duplicated bean definition in xml profiles one in !stage and another in dev

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My application has 3 possible profiles - dev, stage and prod. My spring boot application has a xml config with 2 profiles that seem to be not working.

```
<bean id="globalBean">
    <ref bean="myBean">
</bean>

<beans profile="!stage">
    <bean id="myBean">
        <property name="name" value="notStage" />
    </bean>
    <!--There are more bean definitions here common for dev and prod and have reference to myBean defined above-->
</beans>

<beans profile="dev">
    <bean id="myBean">
        <property name="name" value="dev" />
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="stage">
    <bean id="myBean">
        <property name="name" value="stage" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

In dev mode, my application doesn't somehow pick the dev definition and defaults to the bean definition defined in profile="!stage".

As mentioned I need the profile="!stage" to hold common beans in dev and prod.

Comment: It is not exactly clear at to what you are trying to achieve however your premise of using profile to define different version of `myBean` seems flawed. if your profile is dev then both `profile="dev"` and `profile="!stage"` conditions are true hence one of them will always overwrite the other. Try revisiting the logic of defining those beans and the use of profile

Answer (score 0):

Specifying profile as `dev` matches both `!stage` and `dev`.

you can define multiple profiles in bean declaration like this

```
<beans profile="dev, prod">
```

You can defines bean declarations common to dev and prod here

Comment: This worked, also I had dev as default profile so profile="dafault, prod" worked for me.

Comment: Cannot upvote since I have not reached the reputation score yet, but thank you for your help.